# Working on an Octopress blog from a new computer without source branch?

Tags: github, jekyll, octopress

I've recently changed computers, and accidentally deleted my local version with all the source (Markdown files etc). No matter I thought, it's all in Github (I use GitHub pages), so I'll be able to go from there. However, I've gone into Github and my source branch isn't there (It's quite possible that I never generated it in the first place!).

Is there therefore a quick way to be able to publish with a new source branch without losing all my previous blog posts? Or can I regenerate the markdown from Master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I fixed this now by [writing a script](https://gist.github.com/pezholio/5299018) that scrapes the generated site and recreates the posts:

https://gist.github.com/pezholio/5299018

Simply clone your master branch, clone the Octopress source (into a different folder), download the gist to your source folder and run as follows:

`ruby import.rb {path}`

(Where `{path}` is the full path to your cloned github pages master branch)

You'll also need to sort out your settings and theme, but you're on your own there!

Comment: I also blogged the whole process [here](http://blog.pezholio.co.uk/2013/04/lost-the-source-to-my-octopress-blog-ooops/) in case you've come from Google and done the same thing.